# Permissions error when sudo-ing

Tags: permissions, sudo

I'm following a simple installation guide and I have a noob question. The software I'm installing is Movim (the guide: https://github.com/movim/movim/wiki/Install-Movim)

The 'Downloading' part of the guide instructs me to:
sudo -s -u www-data

When I run this command I get a:

```
root@linux:/var/www# sudo -s -u www-data

bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied

www-data@linux:/var/www$
```

I have tried changing /etc/passwd from the nologin to /bin/bash:

```
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/bash
```

But I get the same error. If I proceed anyway with copying the source code from the repository using git I get:

```
www-data@linux:/var/www$ git clone https://github.com/movim/movim.git 

fatal: could not create work tree dir 'movim'.: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong? Without making the system insecure, what can I do to proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you should be installing this? It seems like you need some experience running web servers to operate this Movim thing.

Comment: Let's say I have some experience. Probably the best way to get better is by doing exactly this, no? :)

Comment: the first error is because you are running in root. maybe that is why the second is failing.... I would open a terminal under the users account not under root and see if you have the same issues

Comment: @JohnOrion I just tried it out of curiousity and got `bash: /home/username/.bashrc: Permission denied`

Comment: That was fantastic John Orion! Thank you! I don't get that first error anymore. But I still have the second one I'm now not sure if I should change the user or group for /var/www coz right now I have: drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Apr 29 14:18 www

Comment: www should be group and user www-data:www-data .... use `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www` this will set the proper owner for your www directory and all the files underneath

Comment: the permission denied error is because you are in a directory and .bashrc is owned by the username but you are changing the user to www-data with that command so it doesn't have rights to access that file

Comment: And just like that you solved my problem. Thank you so much! I owe you a beer.

Comment: BTW one more question guys. This is my first post so you're going to laugh but I can't for the life of me find where I can mark an answer correct. I swear I feel like an idiot right now lol

Comment: glad I can help... you can help me by upvoting the comments that helped you :D.... the little up arrow above the flag by my comments :D .. dont click the flag :D lol

Comment: well in this case .. no one really posted an answer .. as i just stated  you can upvote with the little arrow by the comment on the left when you hover over it ... if there was a answer posted you can click the check mark on the post

Comment: lol if you want i can post my replies as an answer and you can mark it :D

Comment: lol you're laughing! I feel like such a dork right now coz when I hover I don't see that I even changed browsers haha. I do see an X for my own comment. Yes please post as an answer. Both the logging in as another user and then sudoing and the chown helped :)

Comment: Ok maybe I don't have a good enough rank to vote coz this is my first question here. I was able to see the upvote link in my mobile app but it errors out saying 'You cannot vote for this comment' :/

Comment: Yeah you can't vote until you have something like 15 reputation. You can find details about ranks on your profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve issue one you need to be in a user terminal not a root terminal when you make the command.

The command `sudo -s -u www-data` is changing the user to www-data but in the root home directory which `.bashrc` is not accessible to the user www-data.

The second issue is that  your /var/www directory has the wrong  permissions and is set  for root as owner and root as group . This should be set to www-data for both.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

once you have made  these changes you should have less issues